# Can I include a class inside an method?

Tags: php

Just for the case the autoload thing won't work, I wonder if it's fine with PHP to include a class inside a method?

Example:

```
public method doSomething() {
   include ('MyClass.php');
   $foo = MyClass::doAnotherThing();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do that.  In fact, that's exactly what the auto-loading does anyway, since `__autoload()` is itself a function, and you generally use it to look around for your class file to load.

If you manually include your class files like that however, you'll definitely want to use `require_once()` rather than `include()` or `require()`, otherwise you'll get a duplicate declaration of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this works fine, and the class will be available in the global scope. If the file contains other code than a class, that code will be executed as if it was inside the function, though.

Answer (score 1):

Well in that case you probably want to do a `require` or `require_once` and probably test if the `class_exists`, but yes you can do that.